# What determines the block's timestamp?

Tags: block, timestamp, time

As a miner, what happens if I propogate a block with a future timestamp, or yesterday's timestamp? What determines the block time? Can I just give any time here or is it okay to change it with 1-2 seconds?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp of a block must be higher than the median of the timestamps of the past 11 blocks. It also needs to be less than 2 hours in the future (wall clock) at the time of validation.

Note how a block invalid by the second rule can become valid eventually.

Comment: So what you are saying is there can be a recent block whose timestamp has a previous date than the latest block?

Comment: Yes, as long as its timestamp is higher than the median of the past 11 blocks.